# error starting spyder on Ubuntu 15.0

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu, anaconda, glib

Currently on update version of Ubuntu 15.10 and updated most recent version of Anaconda2

```
$ python -V
Python 2.7.11 :: Anaconda 2.5.0 (64-bit)
```

I get this in terminal but spyder opens up and seems fine.

```
GLib-GIO-Message: Using the 'memory' GSettings backend.  Your settings will not be saved or shared with other applications.

(python:21685): Gtk-WARNING **: GModule (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/immodules/im-ibus.so) initialization check failed: GLib version too old (micro mismatch)

(python:21685): Gtk-WARNING **: Loading IM context type 'ibus' failed

(python:21685): Gtk-WARNING **: GModule (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/immodules/im-ibus.so) initialization check failed: GLib version too old (micro mismatch)

(python:21685): Gtk-WARNING **: Loading IM context type 'ibus' failed

(python:21685): Gtk-WARNING **: GModule (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/immodules/im-ibus.so) initialization check failed: GLib version too old (micro mismatch)

(python:21685): Gtk-WARNING **: Loading IM context type 'ibus' failed
```

It's telling me my GLIB version is too old. Well, I am too old but I dont see why it has to be glib about it (groan). Anyway, is there a recommended solution besides ignoring these warnings?

Answer (score 1):

Found [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2306168) that this error can be related to anaconda installing PyQt5 alongside native PyQt4.

Comment: I have the same warning as in the question, with PyQT version 4.11.4 (obtained from the script [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt/Getting%20the%20version%20numbers%20of%20Qt,%20SIP%20and%20PyQt) )